# Authorisation failure with deferred transaction

Tags: smart-contract, deferred-transactions

I have a contract action that does some cleanup:

```
void token::cleanup() { ... }
```

that I want to run asynchronously from another action like this: `schedule("cleanup", 10)`.  my scheduling method looks like this:

```
void token::schedule(std::string proc, int delay)
{   
    transaction t;
    t.actions.emplace_back(
        permission_level{_self, name("active")},
        _self, name(proc),
        std::make_tuple()
    );  
    t.delay_sec = delay;
    t.send(now(), _self);
}
```

but when run, it generates the error below.  I've read many questions on the subject but usually they concern sending an action to another contract.  in my case I just want to call my own contract.  what am I missing?

> error 2019-02-03T23:23:02.511 thread-0  http_plugin.cpp:580
>   handle_exception     ] FC Exception encountered while processing
>   chain.push_transaction debug 2019-02-03T23:23:02.511 thread-0 
>   http_plugin.cpp:581           handle_exception     ] Exception
>   Details: 3100006 subjective_block_production_exception: Subjective
>   exception thrown during block production Authorization failure with
>   sent deferred transaction consisting only of actions to self
>       {}
>       thread-0  apply_context.cpp:347 schedule_deferred_transaction transaction declares authority '{"actor":"t","permission":"active"}',
>   but does not have signatures for it under a provided delay of 10000
>   ms, provided permissions [{"actor":"t","permission":"eosio.code"}],
>   provided keys [], and a delay max limit of 3888000000 ms
>       {"auth":{"actor":"t","permission":"active"},"provided_delay":10000,"provided_permissions":[{"actor":"t","permission":"eosio.code"}],"provided_keys":[],"delay_max_limit_ms":3888000000}
>       thread-0  authorization_manager.cpp:520 check_authorization

incidentally, I'm working with CDT 1.5.0

---

from reading the error message more thoroughly I can see that the permissions provided consist of "eosio.code"... the contract is deployed under the "t" account with the active permission i.e. "t@active" so I don't understand where the "eosio.code" is coming from...

Comment: you are using the transaction action of eosio.token contract. So you need to provide the premission for that. You are converting a string into a name type are you sure this is fine.?

Comment: you can provide the permission for an account like this: `cleos set account permission sender active '{"threshold": 1,"keys": [{"key": "private_keyof this account","weight": 1}],"accounts": [{"permission":{"actor":"account1","permission":"eosio.code"},"weight":1}]}' owner -p account2` this is how i provide the permission to account2

Answer (score 4):

as Nirdesh alluded to in the comments, when a transaction is deferred, it is run by the `eosio` account and therefore that account needs to be given permission to make the call.  Nirdesh's solution above is more complete but the very minimum required to make it work is:

```
cleos set account permission --add-code t active
```

where `t` is the name of the account that owns the contract containing the deferred transaction

the solution was provided by @cc32d9 on the Telegram group